# Selenium Invalid Argument when added driver.get() value from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

**Update/Solution**

I decided to rework the code a little. I ended up using pandas read_csv instead to open the urls.csv and iterated over the df columns with iterrows(). Everything is working now. Below is the updated code snippet.

```
df = pd.read_csv(urls, header=0, encoding="utf8", index_col=False)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    report_type = row[0]
    report_name = row[1]
    file_name = row[2]
    download_report(report_type, report_name, file_name)
```

**----**

I am working on automation some report downloads using Selenium. I wrote the original python script that was too repetitive so I decided to combine thing into a function. This function navigates to a specific place in the system, generates a report by matching a name, downloads the report and moves/renames it.

```
def download_report(q_type, report_name, file):
    driver.get(q_type)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='SavedQueriesDropDownList']/option[text()='%s']" % report_name).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Run Query']").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('exportsLinksDiv').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ListToolbarRAWEXCELExportLink').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    filename = max([path + "\\" + f for f in os.listdir(path)], key=os.path.getctime)
    print(filename)
    os.rename(filename, out_path + file)
```

I have all of my data that the function needs in a csv file that includes three columns: q_type which it the starting URL path, report_name which tells the driver which report to select and file which is a file name that I want the downloaded file to be renamed as.

I am passing the needed value to the function with the following:

```
with open(urls, encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
      for row in reader:
          report_type = row[0]
          report_name = row[1]
          file_name = row[2]
          download_report(report_type, report_name, file_name)
```

When I run the script I get an error on the first line of the function driver.get(q_type):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/nf4.py", line 52, in <module>
    download_report(report_type, report_name, file_name)
  File "C:/nf4.py", line 10, in download_report
    driver.get(q_type)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

For testing I printed out the value of q_type from the function and can confirm that it pulls the url from the csv file and it pulls it as a string. Really not sure where the error is coming from.

I am using the following driver setup:

```
# Setup Chrome Driver
chrome_path = r'C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : r'C:\data-in\raw'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: don't know Python, but this doesn't look right:  ...'%s']" % report_name

Comment: Just to rule out a possibility, can you remove the options=chrome_options parameter to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @jmq nope same thing.

Comment: Try hardcoding the the url in `driver.get("hardcoded URL")` from the `print(q_type)`. If you are able to update the question with your URL that is throwing this error, that would help. Also, you only have to set `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` once, it's ***implicit*** so it will wait for all `find_element` calls once set. It does not act as a `time.sleep()`.

Comment: If you could put your entire `stacktrace` into the question that would help as well, I would like to see what combination of chrome and chromedriver you are on.

Comment: @PixelEinstein I did try to hardcode the URL and it works just fine. As I mentioned, I originally had everything hardcoded and it worked but I wanted to turn this into a function so I didn't have the same code written out 10 times (that's how many reports I need to grab).

Comment: @PixelEinstein I updated the question with the full error traceback.

Comment: It shows you are passing `report_type` from the csv file, can you show the general layout of your csv file? It's hard to test this when we don't have a full picture of the issue. Also try setting your encoding to `utf-8` instead of `utf8`. Also, if you could run this `print(type(q_type), q_type)` and share what it says before the `driver.get` that would really help.

Comment: @PixelEinstein I was actually about to post an update. I got it to work by opening the csv with pd.read_csv and then did a for loop with iterrows(). Thanks for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 14):

I suspect that your q_type does not have a leading http:// (or https://) in front of the URL.  That would cause the error message you are seeing.  Can you verify if this is the case?

Comment: Nope. Its a full https:// url. When I print it in the function for testing I can click on the output in the console and it takes me right to the page I need to load with driver.get()

Comment: Can you add the name of the driver to the question (i.e. Chrome/FireFox driver)?  If you are using ChromeDriver the --verbose and --log-level=DEBUG options may give you more information.

Comment: Just added my driver info to the question.